# Does IE 8 pre-download?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

If I browse to a static web page that contains a direct link to a zip file, will IE 8 attempt to pre-download the zip file?  Or would it in any way send a GET request for that specific file without me clicking on the link explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not.

Preload grabs html/js/images only. Basically things that are required to render a page.